# Есть ли аналог prompt для Node.JS в консоли?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Можно ли получать ответы от пользователя в консоли, когда запускаешь Node сервер?
Например, как аналог `prompt()` из JS, когда тебе предлагают ввести число,   должно быть так же, только в терминале на Node.JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно работать со стандартным вводом данных `stdin`, можете либо сами писать обработчик [раз](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html), [два](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) либо использовать готовые библиотеки, например [prompt](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt)