# node js: есть ли аналог cin >> n; из c++?

Tags: node.js

Я хочу подучить работу с js при помощи сайта https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/.

Там есть возможность сдавать простые задачки (ну, типа, "найти сумму элементов массива") на платформе node.js, и это здорово!

Попробуем решить перую задачу: "в первой строке вводится число элементов N. Затем вводится N целых чисел . Напечатайте их сумму"

Но есть небольшая проблема.

я не умею вводить с консоли что то в ноду. Выводить - умею, есть console.log().

Пробую самый простой способ:

```
    console.log('input n:');
    var n = process.stdin.read();
    console.log('n*n:');
    console.log(n*n);
```

После запуска этого файла в ноде - результат пародоксальный: нода, не останавливаясь на ввод строки, пишет:

```
  node app.js
  input n:
  n*n:
  0
```

и... повисает. Не знаю, чего уж она там ждет, я прервал её ctrl-с.

Гуглю дальше.

Нахожу пример:

```
    const readline = require('readline');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
        console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

        rl.close();
    });
```

- и вижу, что это пример мою проблему не решает.

А как его поменять, если мне надо ввести две строки? А если надо ввести что то в цикле?

Конечно, я могу попробовать завести глобальные переменные, котрые будут в этом question менять вопрос и записывать переменную answer в какой то вектор, а еще изобрести машину состояний, чтобы понять, когда пора это процесс прекратить... но как то это уже очень стрельба из пушки по воробьям. не должно быть так сложно.

В общем, я понимаю, что без какого то аналога ввода с клавиатуры типа `cin >> x;` в c++ я не могу выполнить ни одного учебного примера, и примера такого ввода тоже найти не могу.

почитал про библиотеку promt, и изучил похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771736/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-prompt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-node-js-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8) - но фактически там нет ответа на вопрос: там есть ссылка на 2 места в документации, и нет примера, как эти функции применить для решения моей задачи.

Не подскажете ли Вы мне такой пример?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вероятно, там должен быть пример, как писать код?

Comment: удивительно, но примеры есть для пяти или шести других языков, кроме js. Причем, это общая беда: уе несколько раз за последние месяцы встречал тесты, которые формально можно сдавать на js, он присутствует в списке языков, но даже организаторы тестов на мой вопрос отвечали в духе "попробуйте пройти тестирование на другом языке"

Comment: я наконец наткнулся на что то близкое по смыслу здесь: https://nodeguide.ru/doc/modules-you-should-know/read/ Буду проверять, поддерживается ли var read = require('read'); на учебном сайте, и потом напишу о результатах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это делается на чистом node.js:

```
// @ts-check
const readline = require('readline');

(async () => {

  try {
    const count = await askInteger('Введите количество элементов: ');
    const arr = [];
    while (arr.length < count) {
      try {
        const number = await askInteger(`Введите число #${1 + arr.length}: `);
        arr.push(number);
      } catch (err) {}
    }

    const sum = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc += x, 0);
    console.log(sum);
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

})();

/**
 * @param {*} question
 * @returns {Promise<number>}
 */
async function askInteger(question) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(question, (answer) => {
      rl.close();

      /** @type {number} */
      let number;
      if (answer !== null && answer !== undefined && answer !== '') {
        number = +answer;
      }
      
      return Number.isInteger(number) ? resolve(number) : reject('INCORRECT_INPUT');
    });
  });
}
```

---

Версия на callback-ах:

```
// @ts-check
const readline = require('readline');

run();

function run(){
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  askInteger(rl, 'Введите количество элементов: ', (count) => {
    fillArray(rl, count, undefined, (arr) => {
      rl.close();

      const sum = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc += x, 0);
      console.log(sum);
    });
  });
}

function fillArray(rl, count, arr=[], cb) {
  askInteger(rl, `Введите число #${1 + arr.length}: `, (number) => {
    arr.push(number);
    if (arr.length !== count) {
      fillArray(rl, count, arr, cb);
    } else {
      cb(arr);
    }
  });
}

function askInteger(rl, question, cb) {
  rl.question(question, (answer) => {
    /** @type {number} */
    let number;
    if (answer !== null && answer !== undefined && answer !== '') {
      number = +answer;
    }

    if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
      cb(number);
    } else {
      console.warn('INCORRECT_INPUT');
      askInteger(rl, question, cb);
    }
  });
}
```

---

> console.log('input n:');
>
> var n = process.stdin.read();
>
> console.log('n*n:');
>
> console.log(n*n);
>
> После запуска этого файла в ноде - результат парадоксальный: нода, не останавливаясь на ввод строки, пишет и... повисает. Не знаю, чего уж она там ждет, я прервал её ctrl-с.

`process.stdin` - это stream (фундаментальная штука в node.js).

```
process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk);
});
```

Почитайте https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html - самый интересный раздел документации

Comment: понятно, что оптимальнее `const rl` не объявлять на каждый вызов `askInteger`

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой подробный пример! Конечно, понять его я не смог - я не особо понимаю, что такое промайсы... Зато прикольно, что ввод числа выеделн в отдельную функцию, и с асинк-авейтами можно писать почти нормальный последовательный код.
,

Comment: @S.H. вам нужно пояснение про асинхронность node.js и использование Promise и async-await или вы нормально с этим разобрались?

Comment: Ну, из всего перечисленного я не работал только с промайсами. я даже когдаписал на js - просто избегал их использования

Comment: nodejs асинхронна и неиспользование Promise возможно лишь если вместо них используют колбеки или синхронные операции. в серьёзном коде вложенность колбеков порождает очевидные проблемы поддержки кода. использование синхронных операций нивелирует все приемущества nodejs. если бы я кому-то что-то советовал за современный js то первым советом был бы: научись использовать Promise и научись думать в асинхронных, неблокирующих цепочках операций

Comment: Да, я использовал колбэки. Мне с ними как то всё было поняятнее. Спасибо за совет, я попробую еще раз сделать "подход к снаряду"

Comment: добавил версию на callback-ах, если они вам понятнее

Comment: Спасибо большое, это ОЧЕНЬ большая забота и труд. Теперь я просто обязан осводить синтаксис промайсов! Причем, на самам деле, непонятен там только синттаксис...