# Стандартные ввод/вывод для решения задач на JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, argv, readline

Решил порешать простые задачки на JS, то бишь на Node.JS, столкнулся с проблемой ввод/вывод. Нашел способ readline. Задачку по выводу суммы двух вводных чисел решил так:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const arr = [];

rl.on('line', line => {
  arr.push(line);
  if(arr.length === 2) {
    console.log(Number(arr[0]) + Number(arr[1]));
    rl.close();
  }
})
```

И мне кажется это ооочень некрасиво! Мне кажется, что я не до конца разобрался с этим readline, а может быть даже с JS, я просто привык в C# просто ввел string a = Console.ReadLine(); и дальше работай себе спокойно с этой переменной. Но тут не могу догадаться как можно красивей сделать. Еще увидел работу с командной строкой node.js, там есть process.argv, с ним всё понятно и вот как раз уже похоже на правду, но для него нужно передать числа сразу же при вызове node. Так вот, мой вопрос: правильно ли я понял, что стандартный ввод/вывод для задачек на node.js - это readline? И если да, то не подскажите, пожалуйста, как улучшить мой код? А то как-то меня смущает работа с массивом да и вообще куча строчек для такой маленькой задачи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214723/node-js-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-cin-n-%d0%b8%d0%b7-c/1214972#1214972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И мне кажется это ооочень некрасиво!

Вполне нормально.

> я просто привык в C# просто ввел string a = Console.ReadLine(); и дальше работай себе спокойно с этой переменной

Да, но там поток выполнения заблокирован ожиданием пользовательского ввода, а вот нода, без всяких ухищрений, ожидая ввод, может выполнить ещё мириады полезных вещей - обслужить поступившие запросы, сбегать до Луны за пивом, почистить зубы, поспать, получить ввод, запросить следующий, обслужить запрос.

Ожидание события не блокирует процесс.

> Так вот, мой вопрос: правильно ли я понял, что стандартный ввод/вывод для задачек на node.js - это readline?

Ну, да. Но таких задачек в жизни мало.

> И если да, то не подскажите, пожалуйста, как улучшить мой код?

В вашем коде есть скрытое потенциальное затруднение: никто не узнает что что-то произошло в callback. Прочите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/2659), чтобы понимать проблему и пути решения.

А код, в 2021году, можно улучшить переписав всё на async-await

```
// @ts-check
const readline = require('readline');

(async () => {
  const limit = 2;
  const arr = [];
  while (1) {
    try {
      const str = await ask(`Введите число #${1 + arr.length}: `);
      const number = +str;
      if (!Number.isNaN(number)) {
        arr.push(number);
      }
      if (arr.length === limit) {
        break;
      }
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  const sum = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0);
  console.log(sum);
})();

/**
 * @param {string} question
 * @returns {Promise<string>}
 */
async function ask(question) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(question, (answer) => {
      rl.close();
      if (answer === null || answer === undefined || !/\S/.test(answer)) {
        return reject();
      }
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
}
```