# Как обеспечить обмен с консолью?

Tags: node.js

Как мне вывести в консоль и ввести из неё?

Думаю, можно сделать как-то через `repl` или `readline`, но не знаю как правильно.

Хочу сделать что-то вроде этого:

```js
console.log(`Введите пример: `);
console.log(eval(process.sdtin));
```

Но это даже близко не работает.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, как создать интерактивный обмен вопросами и ответами в консоли, посмотрите примеры в https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html, там их хватает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const readline = require('readline');

(async () => {
  const answer1 = await ask('Введите пример 1: ');
  const answer2 = await ask('Введите пример 2: ');
  console.log(`ответ1=${answer1}, ответ2=${answer2}`);
})();

/**
 * @param {string} question
 * @returns {Promise<string | null>}
 */
async function ask(question) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question(question, (x) => {
      rl.close();
      if (x === null || x === undefined || !/\S/.test(x)) {
        resolve(null);
      } else {
        resolve(x.trim());
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```bsh
$ node src/ask.js 
Введите пример 1: fff
Введите пример 2: gfew
ответ1=fff, ответ2=gfew
```

И ещё смотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234973/2659), там более сложный пример. Или этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214972/2659).